# SolrJ AddBean problems with UpdateProcessorFactory

Tags: solr, mapping, solrj

I'm trying to get TimestampUpdateProcessorFactory and UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory to work with SolrJ's AddBean method but it's just not working, the fields are not automatically filled on update. For example I have a UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory on the id field of my schema and in order to get the UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory to automatically generate the id on document update, I have to set the id in the Bean to an empty string, because it doesn't work to just set the value to null.

Is there some kind of configuration like omit empty fields for the ObjectBinder or so, to make this work? When I add Documents the classical way via add(new SolrInputDocument()) method it works fine, but not with AddBean. That Object to SolrInputDocument Mapper seems to be doing strange stuff here.

Comment: Since the UUIDUpdateProcessor requires the field to be not present - (`An update processor that adds a newly generated UUID value to any document being added that does not already have a value in the specified field. `). You could add a StatelessScriptUpdateProcessor to unset the field if it's null or empty, or possibly use the `IgnoreFieldUpdateProcessorFactory` if you're never going to use it for updating documents.

Comment: Actually that doesn't sound like a good solution, I hoped there would be some kind of setting for the object binder, if there isn't maybe I should open up a change request I can't be the only one who wants to use the AddBean feature in combination with these UpdateProcessors.